# Concatenating huge amount of text data from the same column Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0.
I want to concatenate the Comments for each student from a table into one huge comment and then output (spool) that to a file.

My table TEACHER_COMMENTS has columns:

```
SID  INT
COMMENTS VARCHAR2(4000)
```

The data looks like this:

```
SID   COMMENTS
1    It has truly been a pleasure getting to know your child this quarter. our child has made great progress across the curriculum since the beginning of the school year.
1    Your child has done a very nice job this quarter, taking pride in her work and completing assignments with quality in mind.. Your child has made very good academic and/or social progress this quarter.
```

I want to combine the comments for the same student into one huge comment.

Here is my code:

```
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON
set underline off
set pages 0
set lines 1500
set feedback off
set autop off
set term off
set ver off
set timing off
set time off

spool E:\Test\Comments.csv

SELECT wm_concat(COMMENTS) FROM  TEACHER_COMMENTS t GROUP BY SID;

spool off;

exit;
```

This just outputs one line of comments and not the whole huge comment.

I have also tried using LIST_AGG

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COMMENT, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COMMENT) AS All_Comments
FROM  TEACHER_COMMENTS t
GROUP BY SID
```

This throws an error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

How do I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

**LISTAGG** returns `VARCHAR2 (or RAW)` and therefore is limited to 4000 bytes. And `SQL*Plus` by default has linesize 80.

One possible solution is to use `XMLAGG` and set `LONG` to a high value. Let's see how it works -

```
SQL> SET LONG 2000000000
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 SID, 'It has truly been A pleasure getting TO know your CHILD
  3  this quarter. our CHILD has made great progress across THE curriculum
  4  since THE beginning OF THE school YEAR.' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1, 'Your child has done a very nice job this quarter, taking pride
  6  in her work and completing assignments with quality in mind.. Your child
  7  has made very good academic and/or social progress this quarter.' FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,comments,',').EXTRACT('//text()')
 10  ORDER BY sid).GetClobVal(),',') as long_comments
 11  FROM DATA
 12  /

LONG_COMMENTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
It has truly been A pleasure getting TO know your CHILD
this quarter. our CHILD has made great progress across THE curriculum
since THE beginning OF THE school YEAR.,Your child has done a very nice job this
 quarter, taking pride
in her work and completing assignments with quality in mind.. Your child
has made very good academic and/or social progress this quarter.


SQL>
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you have 11.2 you should be able to use listagg.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(comments, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sid) AS BIGCOMMENT
FROM   teacher_comments
GROUP BY sid;
```

I can't recall if listagg returns a clob, but if it does I would follow the advice of Jon Heller before using the SQL above. You definitely want to stop using wm_concat though.

Comment: `LISTAGG` doesn't return a `CLOB`, it returns `VARCHAR2 or(RAW)`.